# The page isn't redirecting properly error http - https auto redirect showing error in website

Tags: html, .htaccess, https

Whenever i put the below http - https auto redirect code i get this error "The page isn't redirecting properly

An error occurred during a connection to "Website URL".
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."

The htaccess code is below.

```
 # Rewrite engine code https redirect
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # Rewrite engine code for www to non ww version of website
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a test, because at the moment you run the first rule for each request.
And redirect without www before https only.

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on
# http(s)://(www.)?domain   ->  https://domain
# www -> https without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
# http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hey @croises, Thanks for your help man, it works like cake now. Appreciate it!

Comment: Hey @croises, I'm unable to find-out what was my mistake though, can you please throw some more light on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I said, You must add a test before (RewriteCond), because you run the first rule for each request